# Swift - Set label to be on top of other view items

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a basic sketching app using swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.4. The feature I'm working on is adding text to the image for future manipulation.

So far I have the text the user enters adding to the drawing via label, but it is being placed (I assume) behind the `UIImage` that is to be drawn upon. This is preventing the associated tap gesture from being recognised. The label is also obscured when drawn over.

How do I place the label on top of everything else to prevent it being drawn over? The end goal is to allow the user to move the label.

If I was using my usual web stack I'd set the `z-index` of the element to a high value via CSS.

Edit: Using `view.bringSubviewToFront(label)` prevents the text from being drawn over, but does not allow the tap gesture to be picked up.

Heres my code:

```
    func printText(){
        println(textString)

        var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5, 100, 200, 50 ))
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = textString;

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap"))
        label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        self.view.addSubview(label);
    }

    func handleTap() {
        print("tap working")
    }
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you want z-index use:

```
label.layer.zPosition = 1;
```

Also you could play with bringToFront method on the parent view:

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(label);
```

You can check that function here : 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/

Also, you should add the following:

```
label.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

to enable touches.

Comment: Both of these stop the label being drawn over, but the tap gesture is still not being picked up.

Comment: because you are missing label.userInteractionEnabled = true

Answer (score 5):

Try using those in the parent view:

```
view.bringSubviewToFront(label)
view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
```

It all depends on what you can, or want to do.

Comment: This prevents the label from being drawn over (which is awesome), but does not allow tap gesture to be picked up.

Comment: Btw. this is exactly the same answer I offered.

Comment: There is only a 5 minute gap between answers, I did not see your answer as I did not refresh the window. Also, you did not mention the sendSubviewToBack, which also may be usefull.

Answer (score 3):

You can call label to front by

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(label)
```

or

You can send image view to the back by

```
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
```

Comment: This prevents the label from being drawn over, but does not allow tap gesture to be picked up

Comment: exactly the same answer offered by Rafal and me.

Comment: Sorry, but I just checked the question, not the answers provided by others.